# sql update statement not working from Java but working manually?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

EDIT: I had a letter off, it's working now.

I have the following sql statement

```
UPDATE names set sent_count = sent_count + 1  where user_name = 'name' AND category = 'test' AND service = 'test'
```

this works by increasing the sent_count each time I run the sql from PGAdmin3, but I have the following method in a Java program using Postgresql JDBC, it's not throwing any exceptions but it's not increasing sent_count here is the method below

```
public void increaseUsernameResponseCount(String userName, String category, String service, String country) throws SQLException
{
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    // ResultSet rs = null;

    try
    {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
        pst = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE names set sent_count = sent_count + 1  where user_name = ? AND category = ? AND service = ?");
        pst.setString(1, userName);
        pst.setString(2, category);
        pst.setString(3, service);

        int count = pst.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println(count);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    finally
    {
        pst.close();
        conn.close();
    }
}
```

the count counter prints 0 when this method is ran. Any idea why it does not work from the method but it works when I execute the sql query?

Comment: I take it you've made absolutely sure that `userName`, `category` and `service` are exactly the same as in your pgadmin session?

Comment: Use `System.out.println` to print the values of username, category, service.

Comment: And of course make sure you're connecting to the same database, and not some UAT copy or something (been there :))

Comment: Try use profiler to explore sql command,that sent to DB.

Comment: @ Hamlet Hakobyan - probably meant a debugger?

Comment: you guys are right, I had a letter off. Its all good now.

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have two databases containing the same table. This generally happens if you work at two different locations and keep changing database names while importing it from the dump.

Also check if the "url" and "props" strings are correct for the database.